RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn when using foolbox attack
I'm trying to implement PuVAE classifier model followed Lightning Hydra template. After training, I want to use foolbox attack (FGSM and PGD) at test step for my model but got this error. I know that FGSM and PGD require gradient to attack and I've already set my classifier at training mode in test step, x.requires_grad = True
from typing import Any, Dict, Tuple

import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from lightning import LightningModule
from torchmetrics import MeanMetric
from torchmetrics.image import PeakSignalNoiseRatio, StructuralSimilarityIndexMeasure
from torchmetrics.classification.accuracy import Accuracy
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
from src.models.components.classifier import Classifier
from src.models.components.puvae_model import PuVAE
import foolbox as fb

class PuVAEClassifierModule(LightningModule):

    def __init__(
        self,
        net: PuVAE,
        optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
        scheduler: torch.optim.lr_scheduler,
        compile: bool,
        classifier: Classifier,
        pretrained_classifier_path: str = "ckpt.pt",  # path to your pre-trained classifier
        threshold:float=0.12,
        ce_coeff:float=10,
        rc_coeff:float=0.01,
        kl_coeff:float=0.1
    ) -> None:
        """Initialize a `MNISTLitModule`.

        :param net: The model to train.
        :param optimizer: The optimizer to use for training.
        :param scheduler: The learning rate scheduler to use for training.
        """
        super().__init__()

        # this line allows to access init params with 'self.hparams' attribute
        # also ensures init params will be stored in ckpt
        self.save_hyperparameters(logger=False)

        self.net = net
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.classifier = classifier # Load pre-trained classifier weights

        classifier_ckpt = torch.load(pretrained_classifier_path, map_location=self.device)
        state_dict = classifier_ckpt['state_dict']
        new_state_dict = {k.replace('net.', ''): v for k, v in state_dict.items()}
        self.classifier.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
        self.classifier.eval()
        for param in self.classifier.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

        self.criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() # for classifier
        self.bce = torch.nn.BCELoss() # for reconstruction
        self.ce_coeff = ce_coeff
        self.rc_coeff = rc_coeff
        self.kl_coeff = kl_coeff

        # just measure acc during test time
        self.test_acc = Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=10)

        # for averaging loss across batches
        self.train_loss = MeanMetric()
        self.val_loss = MeanMetric()
        self.test_loss = MeanMetric()

        self.val_psnr = PeakSignalNoiseRatio()
        self.val_ssim = StructuralSimilarityIndexMeasure()
        self.test_psnr = PeakSignalNoiseRatio()
        self.test_ssim = StructuralSimilarityIndexMeasure()

    def forward(self, x, y) -> torch.Tensor:
        """Perform a forward pass through the model `self.net`.

        :param x: A tensor of images.
        :return: A tensor of logits.
        """
        return self.net(x, y)

    def model_step(
        self, batch: Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]
    ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        """Perform a single model step on a batch of data.

        :param batch: A batch of data (a tuple) containing the input tensor of images and target labels.

        :return: A tuple containing (in order):
            - A tensor of losses.
            - A tensor of predictions.
            - A tensor of target labels.
        """
        x, y = batch
        reconstruction, kl_loss = self.net(x, y)

        # calculate loss
        rc_loss = self.bce(reconstruction, x)
        vae_loss = self.rc_coeff * rc_loss + self.kl_coeff * kl_loss

        return reconstruction, vae_loss


    def test_step(self, batch: Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor], batch_idx: int) -> None:
        """Perform a single test step on a batch of data from the test set.

        :param batch: A batch of data (a tuple) containing the input tensor of images and target
            labels.
        :param batch_idx: The index of the current batch.
        """
        with torch.enable_grad():
            self.classifier.train()
            x, y = batch
            reconstruction, vae_loss= self.model_step(batch)
            preds = self.classifier(reconstruction)
            
            clean_ce_loss = F.cross_entropy(preds.float(), y.float())
            clean_loss = self.ce_coeff * clean_ce_loss + vae_loss
            clean_psnr = self.test_psnr(reconstruction, x)
            clean_ssim = self.test_ssim(reconstruction, x)

            # Log adversarial attacks
            # self.log_adversarial_attacks(batch, reconstruction, preds)
            x.requires_grad = True
            # Foolbox Attack Evaluation
            self.foolbox_attack(x, y)

            self.classifier.eval()

        # update and log metrics
        self.test_loss(clean_loss)
        self.test_acc(preds, y)
        self.log("test/loss_clean", self.test_loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test/psnr_clean", clean_psnr, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test/ssim_clean", clean_ssim, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test/acc_clean", self.test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

    def foolbox_attack(self, x: torch.Tensor, y) -> None:

        # Set up Foolbox model and preprocessing if needed
        fmodel = fb.PyTorchModel(self.classifier, bounds=(0, 1))
        
        # Convert labels to the format required by Foolbox
        labels = y.argmax(dim=1) if y.dim() > 1 else y

        # FGSM Attack
        fgsm_attack = fb.attacks.FGSM()
        fgsm_images, _, success_fgsm = fgsm_attack(fmodel, x, labels, epsilons=0.1)  # Adjust epsilon as needed
        fgsm_reconstruction, _ = self.forward(fgsm_images, y)
        fgsm_preds = self.classifier(fgsm_reconstruction)

        # PGD Attack
        pgd_attack = fb.attacks.LinfPGD()
        pgd_images, _, success_pgd = pgd_attack(fmodel, x, labels, epsilons=0.1)  # Adjust epsilon as needed
        pgd_reconstruction, _ = self.forward(pgd_images, y)
        pgd_preds = self.classifier(pgd_reconstruction)

        # Compute and log metrics
        fgsm_acc = (fgsm_preds.argmax(dim=1) == labels).float().mean()
        pgd_acc = (pgd_preds.argmax(dim=1) == labels).float().mean()

        self.log("test/fgsm_acc", fgsm_acc, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test/pgd_acc", pgd_acc, prog_bar=True)

    def configure_optimizers(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        optimizer = self.hparams.optimizer(params=self.trainer.model.parameters())
        if self.hparams.scheduler is not None:
            scheduler = self.hparams.scheduler(optimizer=optimizer)
            return {
                "optimizer": optimizer,
                "lr_scheduler": {
                    "scheduler": scheduler,
                    "monitor": "val/loss",
                    "interval": "epoch",
                    "frequency": 1,
                },
            }
        return {"optimizer": optimizer}


When running, I get this error
 File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/evaluation_loop.py", line 135, in run                                                   
    self._evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx, dataloader_iter)                                                                                                         
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/evaluation_loop.py", line 396, in _evaluation_step                                      
    output = call._call_strategy_hook(trainer, hook_name, *step_args)                                                                                                                
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/call.py", line 319, in _call_strategy_hook                                            
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/strategies/strategy.py", line 425, in test_step                                               
    return self.lightning_module.test_step(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                          
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/PuVAE/src/models/classifier_module.py", line 186, in test_step                                                                                         
    self.foolbox_attack(x, y)                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/PuVAE/src/models/classifier_module.py", line 214, in foolbox_attack                                                                                    
    fgsm_images, _, success_fgsm = fgsm_attack(fmodel, x, labels, epsilons=0.1)  # Adjust epsilon as needed                                                                          
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/foolbox/attacks/base.py", line 283, in __call__                                                                 
    xp = self.run(model, x, criterion, epsilon=epsilon, **kwargs)                                                                                                                    
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/foolbox/attacks/fast_gradient_method.py", line 98, in run                                                       
    return super().run(                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/foolbox/attacks/gradient_descent_base.py", line 155, in run                                                     
    _, gradients = self.value_and_grad(loss_fn, x)                                                                                                                                   
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/foolbox/attacks/gradient_descent_base.py", line 111, in value_and_grad                                          
    return ep.value_and_grad(loss_fn, x)                                                                                                                                             
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eagerpy/framework.py", line 360, in value_and_grad                                                              
    return t.value_and_grad(f, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                      
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eagerpy/tensor/tensor.py", line 553, in value_and_grad                                                          
    return self._value_and_grad_fn(f, has_aux=False)(self, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                          
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eagerpy/tensor/pytorch.py", line 507, in value_and_grad                                                         
    loss.backward()                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 581, in backward                                                                        
    torch.autograd.backward(                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 347, in backward                                                              
    _engine_run_backward(                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/mnt/apple/k66/ptrang/env/puvae/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py", line 825, in _engine_run_backward
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Does anyone know solution? Thank you
